# puppet apply not working

Tags: macos, puppet

I am trying to puppet locally in my mac(OS X). I installed latest versions of puppet, hiera and facter. I created a module with the following structure

```
$ find .
.
./files
./manifests
./manifests/init.pp
./templates
```

and contents of hello_world/manifests/init.pp

```
$ cat manifests/init.pp 
class hello_world { 
   file {'/tmp/itworks':
       ensure  => directory,
   }
}
```

but nothing happens when I run

```
puppet apply hello_world/manifests/init.pp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a class but never `include` it. (The class does not get declared.)

Note that modules are not usually applied directly. Instead, you apply a manifest that `include`s a class from the module (often, the class that is named after the module and automagically located in `module_name/manifests/init.pp`. E.g.

```
puppet apply -e 'include hello_world'
```

Note that the `hello_world/` directory must be located in your `$modulepath` (usually `/etc/puppet/modules` for the open source variant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

puppet apply -e 'include hello_world'

or for a dry run

puppet apply -e 'include hello_world' --noop

For more puppet apply, see manual page : http://docs.puppetlabs.com/man/apply.html